# Inequality with roots and bivariate quadratic forms

Tags: inequality, quadratic-forms

For $|a|\le 1$ and $|b|\le 1$ show that

$$\sqrt{1 - b^2}\sqrt{1 - a} \le  \frac{\sqrt{6}(1-\frac{3}{4}b)(7a^2b^2 + 96a^2b + 65a^2 + 14ab^2 + 42a + 7b^2 - 96b - 135)}{43a^2b^2 + 129a^2 + 86ab^2 - 86a + 43b^2 - 327}
 $$

Numerical checks confirm this involved inequality. I tried expansions of the roots and clearing denominators, but didn't succeed. It holds with equality for $a=b=1$ and $a=-b=1$. Hints are welcome. Since numerator and denominator are bivariate quadratic forms, also a geometric interpretation might be helpful.

Comment: quadratic form? Degree varies from 4 to zero.

Comment: @Macavity Yes. I phrased that somewhat loosely "bivariate quadratic forms" to indicate that the two variables occur at most quadratic. I was trying to avoid "quartic form" since then a single variable can occur in fourth power. If there is a correct term I'm happy to change the formulation.

Answer (score 1):

no idea. The denominator really is nonzero on your square, namely less than zero

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The numerator is also nonpositive.

Comment: I was firstly looking for a general way to approach such a problem, the full solution could wait .....